# Loading view programmatically

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, segue

I have three view controllers in my project. Let's call them view1, view2 and view3. View2 is loaded from View1 using segue from interface builder. But view3 needs to be loaded programmatically from view2 since view2 makes RESTful request to REST server and that request is asynchronous. I have a separate class to handle REST request. Once I get the return value from REST server, I invoke loadResultViewController method of view2. However I'm getting "libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException" error. How do I resolve this issue?

This is my loadResultViewController method

```
func loadResultViewController(summary: String) {
    let resultViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ResultView") as! ResultViewController
    self.presentViewController(resultViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    resultViewController.summary.text = summary

}
```

EDIT:

This is full error message.

> 2015-09-14 14:01:13.645 My Strategic[5307:791826] *** Assertion failure in -[UIKeyboardTaskQueue waitUntilAllTasksAreFinished], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3347.44.2/Keyboard/UIKeyboardTaskQueue.m:374
>   2015-09-14 14:01:13.678 My Strategic[5307:791826] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIKeyboardTaskQueue waitUntilAllTasksAreFinished] may only be called from the main thread.'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (
>       0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010345dc65 **exceptionPreprocess + 165
>       1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000104fc8bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
>       2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010345daca +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106
>       3   Foundation                          0x00000001038fa98f -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 195
>       4   UIKit                               0x00000001044547d6 -[UIKeyboardTaskQueue waitUntilAllTasksAreFinished] + 151
>       5   UIKit                               0x0000000103ef5912 -[UIKeyboardImpl setDelegate:force:] + 473
>       6   UIKit                               0x00000001041a04ad -[UIPeripheralHost(UIKitInternal) _reloadInputViewsForResponder:] + 1002
>       7   UIKit                               0x00000001041a8834 -[UIPeripheralHost(UIKitInternal) _preserveInputViewsWithId:animated:reset:] + 504
>       8   UIKit                               0x0000000103e384f1 -[UIViewController _presentViewController:modalSourceViewController:presentationController:animationController:interactionController:completion:] + 623
>       9   UIKit                               0x0000000103e3976e -[UIViewController _presentViewController:withAnimationController:completion:] + 3079
>       10  UIKit                               0x0000000103e3b6c1 __62-[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:]_block_invoke + 132
>       11  UIKit                               0x0000000103e3b5e5 -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 229
>       12  My Strategic                      0x0000000102dbfc26 _TFC14My_Strategic22PostCodeViewController24loadResultViewControllerfS0_FSST_ + 870
>       13  My Strategic                      0x0000000102dc0cae _TTWC14My_Strategic22PostCodeViewControllerS_12RestDelegateS_FS1_24loadResultViewControllerUS1___fQPS1_FSST_ + 94
>       14  My Strategic                      0x0000000102dcfcf0 _TFFC14My_Strategic4Rest9getRidingFS0_FSST_U_FTGSQCSo13NSURLResponse_GSQCSo6NSData_GSQCSo7NSError__T_ + 2960
>       15  My Strategic                      0x0000000102dcfe4a _TTRXFo_oGSQCSo13NSURLResponse_oGSQCSo6NSData_oGSQCSo7NSError__dT__XFdCb_dGSQS__dGSQS0__dGSQS1___dT** + 90
>       16  CFNetwork                           0x000000010566d8c5 **67+[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:]_block_invoke_2 + 155
>       17  Foundation                          0x000000010391e57f __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK** + 7
>       18  Foundation                          0x000000010385f0b2 -[NSBlockOperation main] + 98
>       19  Foundation                          0x0000000103841774 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 645
>       20  Foundation                          0x0000000103841383 __NSOQSchedule_f + 184
>       21  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000106ac2614 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
>       22  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000106aa96a7 _dispatch_queue_drain + 2176
>       23  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000106aa8cc0 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 235
>       24  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000106aac3b9 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 1359
>       25  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000106aadb17 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 111
>       26  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000106e2f637 _pthread_wqthread + 729
>       27  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000106e2d40d start_wqthread + 13
>   )
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Can you post the full error message that you are receiving?

Comment: What did u try? Do u see your response arrive and u parse it correctly? r u sure your completion handler is called to trigger your segue? did u try to call your segue without waiting to response (i.e  to create a button to trigger your segue).

Comment: Yes it parses correctly. The exception arises in presentviewcontroller call. There's no segue between view2 and view3. Do I need one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the relevant part of the error message:

> reason: '-[UIKeyboardTaskQueue waitUntilAllTasksAreFinished] may only be called from the main thread.'

You're making the REST request on a background thread and then when you get the result, you perform the transition on the same thread. All UI code should generally run on the main thread.

Try wrapping the code in the method body in this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
  // your code here
})
```

Comment: I invoke my loadResultViewController from the callback function of NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest since I don't know other way to load the new view once data is received. Anyway, I put REST request code inside your wrapping code, but I'm still getting exception.

Comment: If you updated your code based on @rkunde's answer it should fix your problem. If you're still having errors then add a new section to your question showing your new code, indicating which line is giving the error, and the full text of the error message.

Comment: My bad, I put the REST function inside instead of code that loads new view. It works!

Answer (score 0):

small typo in the suggestion.. the expression block should be prefixed by '^' like below

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // your code here
})
```