# Unhiding label, button do not work

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to unhide controls using the following delegate method from another class.

```
func updateViewController(restData: String) {
    headerLabel.hidden = false
    locationValue.text = restData
    locationValue.hidden = false
    showSummaryButton.hidden = false
}
```

However, it's not working. I'm calling this method from a class that deals with asynchronous REST request. I have created IBOutlet for all those controls and have connected. I have created this function as an attempt to go around the problem I had with loading new view from the REST class. You can see the question - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32571262/loading-view-programatically/32571848#32571848)

Comment: You haven't provided enough information. In general, it's a bad idea to try to manipulate another view controller's views. Instead you should add methods that let some other object tell your view controller what you want it to do.

Comment: BTW, the link you provided relates to trying to update the UI from a background thread, a different subject. The other poster in that thread told you how to fix your problem.

Comment: This method is a delegate method and the view controller I'm manipulating implement this delegate. I'm calling this delegate method from the callback function of REST request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run the code that updates the UI inside 
the main UI thread via the dispatch_async call.

```
func updateViewController(restData: String) 
{
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
    headerLabel.hidden = false
    locationValue.text = restData
    locationValue.hidden = false
    showSummaryButton.hidden = false
  })
}
```